# Fabric Beta Group Alias Not Deleted Even If Group Is Deleted

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm using Fabric's Beta "Manage Groups" feature.

I created a group `project-android` and the alias `project-android` was offered. After that, I decided to delete the group. Now if I try to create the same group name again, the alias offered is `project-android-1`.

If I keep creating and deleting the group with the same name, the alias number will keep incrementing. It seems that the alias is not deleted together with the group. Is there a way to get back the original alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta groups are soft deleted in case they need to be restored at a user's request. Because of this, the alias ID gets incremented if you create a group that uses the same name.

Comment: Does this mean that `project-android` will never become available as group alias?

Comment: Yes. If you delete a group, that alias will not become available again.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!